changing xpath dynamically in selenium - python
Hi Unable code / automate the python script in a loop with dynamically changing xpath's
So, each time i need to input the path manually.
Below are the sample xpath's (actually i have more xpaths to input) and code
HTML Element looks like below:
<i data-v-36de69d2="" aria-label="Play" tabindex="0" role="button" class="zm-icon-play icon"></i>

path1= driver.find_element("xpath",'//*[@id="4cc49c1a-bbef-48d2-9ca2-b804db7be94a"]/div[5]/div/div[2]/div[1]/div/div[1]/div/div/div/div[3]/div/div[1]/i').click()
  
path2= driver.find_element("xpath",'//*[@id="cabfd3f2-83ab-4297-ab49-3efd7e0523f3"]/div[5]/div/div[2]/div[1]/div/div[1]/div/div/div/div[3]/div/div[1]/i').click()


List of xpaths

xpath_1 = //*[@id="4cc49c1a-bbef-48d2-9ca2-b804db7be94a"]/div[5]/div/div[2]/div[1]/div/div[1]/div/div/div/div[3]/div/div[1]/i
xpath_2 = //*[@id="cabfd3f2-83ab-4297-ab49-3efd7e0523f3"]/div[5]/div/div[2]/div[1]/div/div[1]/div/div/div/div[3]/div/div[1]/i  

How can I dynamically code in loop with single xpath from above list.

Share the HTML of the desired element you want to locate using XPath. Edit your question and share the HTML in the form of text. Or if the URL of the page is publicly accessible, share the URL.

if you use for-loop then keep strings on list all_xpaths = [ '//*...', '//*...' ] - and later for xpath in all_xpaths: ... driver.find_element("xpath", xpath).click(). Frankly it is basic knowledge

Thanks shawn , edited the question and posted

Without more HTML or a link to the page it's hard to say but I would start with the code below. Given the HTML you provided, this will grab all icons in a collection, loop through them, and click each one.
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
icons = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "i[aria-label='Play']")))
for icon in icons:
    icon.click()
    # do something

NOTE: Depending on what the click triggers, navigation to a new page or a page reload, this may cause a stale element exception that you will have to adjust for.
